# get max odd number

Tags: c#, max

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] mass = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("display random Massive: \n");
        foreach (var i in mass)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        int max = mass.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("max value in Massive = {0}", max);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

my code gives me max value in massive, I need get max odd value. How to get max odd value?

Comment: For clarification purposes: You are aware of the logic behind odd values, aren't you? Odd values can be devided by to. That's why x Modulo 2 has to be 0 and that would be the condition you need to implement. That's why all the answers include x % 0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
int max = mass.Max();
```

to

```
int max = mass.Where(x=>(x%2)==1).Max();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq` to do this easily

```
mass.Where (x => x % 2 != 0).Max ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easier using linq:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] mass = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => rnd.Next(0, 10)).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine("display random Massive: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", mass));
    Console.WriteLine();
    int max = mass.Where(i => (i & 1) == 1).Max();
    Console.WriteLine("max value in Massive = {0}", max);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Explanations:

- I initialize the array by generating 10 random numbers, converting them to an array
- I output them using `string.Join`
- using `Where` with testing that the last bit is set filters for odd numbers
- calling `Max` on only these odd numbers.

Note that you don't need to use `\n` as `Console.WriteLine` adds a new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming you're a beginner like me and don't understand  linq  yet

Declare a list for holding odd values

```
List<int> oddList = new List<int>();
```

Then in your foreach method

```
foreach (var i in mass) 
    { 

        if (i % 2 != 0) //check that number is odd  

            {
                  oddList.Add(i); //add odd randoms to list 

            {

     } 

Console. WriteLine(oddList.Max().ToString());
```